# Disable/enable toolbar menu item depending on toggle sate

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am working with enable/disable state of toolbar items.

I need to disable second menu until the first one is in toggle on state. For this I try to get toggle state of the first menu item. But the state is always NULL.

```
ICommandService service = (ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().
                                                   getService(ICommandService.class);
Command command = service.getCommand("com.commandID");
State state     = command.getState("org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState");
```

Somebody knows what is the problem? Maybe there is a better way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered ToggleState for your command?

> Since it is possible to have multiple menu contributions for the same
>   command, we have to keep track of the state in a central place.
>   Imagine a toggle button triggerable from the main menu and a views
>   toolbar. The state of these buttons are keept in sync by storing the
>   state directly in the command.  The key to this is the
>   org.eclipse.jface.commands.ToggleState.

```
<command id="org.eclipse.example.command.toggle"
        name="Toggle Me">
  <state class="org.eclipse.jface.commands.ToggleState"
         id="org.eclipse.example.command.toggleState" />
</command>
```

Please read [this blog post](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/01/15/toggling-a-command-contribution/) for more details.